# How Cut out an image and zoom it

Tags: openseadragon

I would like to zoom in with openseadragon but for performance
 reasons i would like to have the opportunity to cut a 
picture and zoom based on the zooming work find just we need this for performance.

Comment: What performance issues are you finding? OpenSeadragon is designed to work with giant images with the same performance as small images, so cutting out a portion of your image shouldn't have any impact on your performance. Anyway, if you want to do that, you'll need to create a new image on your server with just the portion you want to use.

Comment: i need to split image before to use openseadragon

Comment: Cool. Then you'll just need to do some server side image manipulation on your original source image and then convert that into a zooming tile set (assuming it's big enough to need that).